# Why do i get this error?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

**AFTER EDIT**

I get the this error

```
1>     Creating library D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.lib and object D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.exp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

when i run the following code :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_HelloWorld_print( JNIEnv *env , jobject obj) {
printf("Hello World!\n");
return;
 }
```

This is the header file `HelloWorld.h`

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Why do i get this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JNIENv` should be `JNIEnv` (lower case n) as shown by this [Getting Started](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#26865) guide.

Edit: As seems from your error, you should define the project as a DLL, in your case it looks for the main method since it tries to create an executable.

Comment: After resolving to JNIEnv i get this error message `1>     Creating library D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.lib and object D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.exp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>D:\Jni tester\Debug\Jni tester.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals` why is that ?

Comment: I will look at it in an hour. I have to go now.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta - please see edit, also, next time don't remove the question, it takes the answer out of context.

Comment: @ MByD thank you ! what do we mean when we set the project type to `dll` .